# Возвращение нескольких значений функции(1 курс, с++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
int read()
{
   int a, b, n;
   double step;
   cout << "Enter a and b: ";
   cin >> a >> b;
   cout << "Enter n > 1: " << endl;
   cin >> n;
   while (n <= 1)
   {
      cout << "Error! Enter n > 1" << endl;
      cin >> n;
   }
   cout << "Enter step: " << endl;
   cin >> step;
   while (step == 0)
      {
          cout << "Error! Enter step != 0" << endl;
          cin >> step;
      }
   //Как мне вернуть все эти значения//
 }
```

Задание создать функцию для считывания данных, как вернуть все эти значения для использования в другой функции, если return возвращает только одно?

Comment: Запихнуть все значения в одну структуру/класс, например?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вернуть несколько значений функция не может по определению, однако она может сохранить эти значения через переданные ей указатели или ссылки. Например, через ссылки так:

```
void read(int& a, int& b, int& n, double& step)
{
   cout << "Enter a and b: ";
   cin >> a >> b;
   cout << "Enter n > 1: " << endl;
   cin >> n;
   while (n <= 1)
   {
      cout << "Error! Enter n > 1" << endl;
      cin >> n;
   }
   cout << "Enter step: " << endl;
   cin >> step;
   while (step == 0)
      {
          cout << "Error! Enter step != 0" << endl;
          cin >> step;
      }
 }
```

Вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
   int a, b, n;
   double step;

   read(a,b,n,step);
   //a,b,n и step теперь содержат нужные значения
```

Также можно запихнуть значения в структуру и возвращать структуру (об этом написали в комментариях), либо передавать указатель/ссылку на структуру в качестве параметра - результат будет тот же.